# Calculating a metric to compare multiple posterior probability distributions

Tags: probability, estimation

I am beginner in mathematics/statistics and apologise in advance for my faulty use of language. Especially because I assume this to be a simple problem.

I am working on a problem in statistical genetics, where I would like to calculate a metric which I can use to compare probabilities of genotypes across multiple individuals.

For a given individual at a certain genetic position, I have three possible genotype states: `AA`, `AB`, and `BB`. Using an algorithm that estimates how likely it is to observe a genotype, I obtained probabilities for each genotype state at a given position: $p_{AA}$, $p_{AB}$, and $p_{BB}$; which is a posterior probability distribution (probabilities sum to 1).

Let's say I have 2 individuals with 5 corresponding genetic positions each. The resulting probably matrices are

#### Individual 1:

```
position pAA pAB pBB
00000001 0.1 0.2 0.7
00000002 0.8 0.1 0.1
00000003 0.3 0.2 0.5
00000004 0.3 0.3 0.4
00000005 0.8 0.0 0.2
```

#### Individual 2:

```
position pAA pAB pBB
00000001 0.2 0.2 0.6
00000002 0.6 0.4 0.0
00000003 0.3 0.4 0.3
00000004 0.3 0.3 0.4
00000005 0.4 0.3 0.3
```

For the two individuals, the estimation resulted in different genotype probabilities for the same positions (because they are different individuals and can have different genotypes), but for the second individual, estimation was less accurate.

I would like to calculate a metric which allows me to compare the estimation quality.

For this, I simply could use the mean of the max genotype probability in each row. However, I assume this to be less robust when a few positions where estimated with higher probability than the others.

Also, a second problem arrises when individual 2 has more genetic positions:

#### Individual 2:

```
position pAA pAB pBB
00000001 0.2 0.2 0.6
00000002 0.6 0.4 0.0
00000003 0.3 0.4 0.3
00000004 0.3 0.3 0.4
00000005 0.4 0.3 0.3
00000006 0.0 0.0 1.0
00000007 0.0 0.0 1.0
00000008 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Hence, my question comes down to this: Can I compute a metric with which I can compare the estimation results of multiple individuals, which have a variable number of genetic positions?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that your second estimation is less accurate? Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean with metric? In mathematics, a metric is a generalization of a distance function between points; I have the feeling that this is not exactly what you are looking for. Do you want to know how good your estimation is? Would [Confidence Intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) help you?

Comment: In individual 2, overall the estimation resulted in less "confident" probabilities. For example, a distribution of 0 0 1 means that genotype state BB has most confidence, while a distribution of 0.3 0.3 0.4 tells me that the estimation of BB was not confident, as the other states are (almost) equally likely.

Comment: And yes, I think "metric" was the wrong word. Would "score" or "measure" be more appropriate?